# Vertx 3.7.0+ Using the RedisAPI - HMSET

Tags: redis, vert.x

Before Vertx 3.7 we were using the RedisClient to make operations like :

```
    redis.hmset(someString, someJsonObject, res -> {... });
```

The new Redis API should allow a smooth migration as far as it is explained in the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/).

However, this method is not allowed like before. The only available method is:

```
default RedisAPI hmset(List<String> args, Handler<AsyncResult<Response>> handler)
```

How do we go about this?

I have tried passing the params as list but it did not work.

```
redis.hmset(Arrays.asList(someString, someJsonObject.encode()), res -> { });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RedisAPI` follows the redis official documentation which says `hmset` receives a list of arguments in the format: `key, value[, key, value]...`.

I think the `RedisAPI` should be improved to convert `JsonObjects` to a list for this specific example.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up writing util methods to overcome this. (Thanks to Paulo's explanations.)

```
/**
 * Utility method to convert a Json key:value pairs to a list
 * We use this to pass the JSON as an argument to the redis HMSET method
 * https://redis.io/commands/hmset
 * @param json
 * @return
 */
private static List<String> toList(JsonObject json){

    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : json.getMap().entrySet()){
        res.add(e.getKey());
        res.add((String) e.getValue());
    }
    return res;
}




/**
 * Utility method to convert a redis response [key, val, key, val ...] to a Json
 * We use this to parse the JSON from Redis native response
 * @param redisResponse
 * @return
 */
private static JsonObject toJson(Response redisResponse){

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    for (String key : redisResponse.getKeys()){
        json.put(key, redisResponse.get(key).toString());
    }
    return json;
}
```

then it can be used such as :

```
    List<String> args = toList(config);
    args.add(0, "someKey");
    redis.hmset(args, res -> { });
```

and

```
redis.hgetall("someKey", res1 -> {
                    if (res1.succeeded()) {
                        handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(toJson(res1.result())));
```